# При запуске ADB система полностью зависает

Tags: linux, ubuntu, adb, android-adb

При запуске `adb`, например, из командной строки

```
adb start-server
```

пишет что демон успешно запущен, после чего система намертво зависает, изображение экрана не меняется, хоткеи, такие как <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, не работают и т.д. Как можно исправить?

**UPD:** Вывод `strace adb start-server`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать переконфигурировать nanosleep

```
dpkg-reconfigure nanosleep
```

Или очистить данные nanosleep

```
apt-get purge nanosleep
```

nanosleep() это функция языка C, она приостанавливает работу вызывающей нити как минимум на время, заданное параметром *req, или до получения сигнала, который вызовет обработчик в вызывающей нити, или приведёт к завершению процесса. 
Если вы подключаете android, то в его настройках убарите галочку с "измерить время работы adb".
Попробуйте переконфигурировать adb

```
dpkg-reconfigure adb
```

Если не поможет переустановите adb

```
apt-get purege adb
apt-get remove adb
apt-get install adb
```

Или проделайте тоже самое но только с пакетом gcc.

Comment: В обоих случаях `E: Не удалось найти пакет nanosleep`

Comment: Переустановил `adb`, всё тоже самое. Добавил в вопрос вывод `strace`.

Comment: Вы переустанавливали gcc ?

Comment: пытался: http://storage6.static.itmages.com/i/17/0401/h_1491050502_2088687_4d4abeb66f.jpg

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить apt-get update и apt-get upgrade. Выполните apt-get install gcc и apt-get install g++ . Если неполучится, то поищите для пакетов gcc и g++ репозитории и добавте их через командную строку, потом apt-get update и apt-get upgrade.

Comment: После обновлений при попытке установить gcc и g++ пишет, что они уже установлены

Comment: Тогда попробуйте сначала apt-get purge gcc и apt-get remove gcc (это же проделайте с ракетом g++), а затем apt-get install gcc  (это тоже проделайте с g++).

Comment: я уже отправлял, что пишет при попытке удалить `gcc` (4 комментарий).

Comment: Тогда примените ко всем пакетам apt-get install -f , для устранения неудовлетворенных зависимостей.

Comment: оказывается нужно было сначала удалять g++, а потом gcc. Сейчас всё заработало, посмотрим будет ли оно работать дальше. Добавьте пожалуйста в ответ информация про переустановку gcc после g++, что бы она в комментариях не терялась.

Comment: Сегодня включил компьютер и `adb` опять вешает всю систему.

Comment: @Evgeniy Попробуйте переустановить пакет adb. apt-get purge adb , затем apt-get remove adb, apt-get install adb

Comment: сейчас опять перезагрузил - на третий раз adb запустился нормально.

Comment: тоже самое( adb переустановил, gcc и g++ тоже, не помогло

Comment: @Evgeniy можно попробовать установить другую версию adb.

Comment: запускал версию, которая вместе с adnroidStudio ставилось, всё равно зависает

Comment: @Evgeniy попробуйте установить какую-нибудь версию чуть ниже установленной.